# how to customize login url and condition in django simple jwt

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have an app with multi user type, Author, Moderator and Manager. this groups have different android apps. and I've  used django simple JWT token for login. the problem is that Author can login in moderator app and moderator can login in others app and so on.

the question is that,
how can i separate login urls and conditions for these groups??

I have used django user model for authentication, and used django groups for defining three groups. just admin can create users and when he create a user, define user's group.  in simple jwt we use this pattern for authentication

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    ...
]
```

and my authentication backend setting is this:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'account.authentication.MobileAuthBackend',
)
```

all user can login to my apps. not important their groups. because system just check django user model.

now i want to have separate login url for this three android apps and have specific login condition for every groups. but i don't know how should i do that!?

Comment: Please provide more details, particularly code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try it from admin page? You can give different permissions for different users.